# Smaller frame with listings

Tags: beamer, listings, framed

I am using `listings` to put java code in my `beamer` slides.

Sometimes, I want to frame the code but I do not want the frame to occupy
the whole width of the page. I want the frame to occupy only the width of
my code and no more.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution with `fancyvrb` and output with `listings`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{SmallListing}[1][]
  {\lstset{#1}\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{VerbatimOut}{VerbEnv.tmp}}
  {\end{VerbatimOut}\settowidth\@tempdima{%
    \lstinputlisting{VerbEnv.tmp}}
  \minipage{\@tempdima}\lstinputlisting{VerbEnv.tmp}\endminipage}    
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{center}
\begin{SmallListing}
  [language=Java,frame=single,columns=fixed,
   basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\bfseries]
static void main () {
  int foo;
  string baz;
}
\end{SmallListing}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Is it advisable/possible to use `\write18` (or something else) to clean up `VerbEnv.tmp`?

Comment: @Werner: you are right, that should be `\jobname.tmp`, then it is easier to delete. It makes no real sense here to delete that file because we need `-shell-escape`

Comment: Nice tidy approach!

Answer (score 3):

The [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) provides the `varwidth` environment which is similar to `minipage`. However, it fits it's content in a box of "natural" width if the contents is up to a specified maximum:

```
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
...
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
   ...
\end{varwidth}
```

The problem with using the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) is that, as [@Neil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/911/niel-de-beaudrap) mentioned, it wants to take up the entire `\textwidth` for the `lstlisting`. There are other alternatives, like the `algorithmicx` package, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\usepackage{algorithmicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\centering
  \fbox{\begin{varwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \State Here is some code
      \State Some lines or very long compared to others
      \State Some are short.
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Framed algorithmic environment]

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting the `lstlisting` environment in a `minipage`:

```
\begin{center}% if you want
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[...]
but don't indent your source code
unless you want extra white-space
on the left side of your listing!
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

**Edited to add:** using `fancyvrb`, I have found a fantastically cludgy solution, but one which gives exactly the desired output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,listings}
\begin{document}

% The following saves the code in a separate file.
\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
but don't indent your source code
unless you want extra white-space
on the left side of your listing!
\end{lstlisting}
\end{VerbatimOut}

% The following somehow manages to find the natural width of the code!
\newlength\codewidth
\settowidth\codewidth{\input{\jobname.listing}}

% Make a minipage with the natural width of the code.
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\codewidth}%
\input{\jobname.listing}%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Can we tidy this up to allow this mechanism to be captured in a wrapper environment for `lstlisting`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, if I use minipage, I have to choose the width (for example, 0.5\textwidth). What I would like to get is a frame that occupies just the width of my code without having to specify this width.

Comment: @user7137: Indeed. I am interested myself in whether there is a way to do this. However, the `lstlisting` environment seems to want to occupy as much horizontal space as it thinks is allowed.

Comment: @user7137: see my revised answer above for something ugly, but which works automatically.